# java error with ".write"

Tags: java

I'm having a problem here
I am using netbeans!
I am unable to use the .write

Here are my codes:

```
ModFile=new File(NameText.getText() + ".mod");
if(!ModFile.exists()){
try {
  ModFile.createNewFile();
  System.out.println("Mod file has been created to the current directory");
  ModFile.*write*(CodesBox.getText());
  } catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(ModMakerGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
 }
```

This line:

```
ModFile.*write*(CodesBox.getText());
```

is giving me problems!
Please help me here

Comment: Try ModFile.write(CodesBox.getText()); your code doesn't look like it will compile at the moment.

Comment: Is there an error-message? Are the *s wanted? Or did you try to format the text with *?

Comment: `giving me problem` is not a good description of actual problem. Please be specific about your issue. Are you getting some error? If yes, post the exact error message here.

Comment: You should at least add the error you get.

Comment: Have a look at the following link for details on how to ask better questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @looper : I think * is the OP's attempt to highlight the code section

Comment: @PaulWhelan : I think * is the OP's attempt to highlight the code section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File does not have write method. Please use FileWriter or Print Writer

```
ModFile=new File(NameText.getText() + ".mod");
FileWriter writer=null;
if(!ModFile.exists()){
try {
  ModFile.createNewFile();
writer=new FileWriter(ModFile);
  System.out.println("Mod file has been created to the current directory");
  writer.write(CodesBox.getText());
  } catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(ModMakerGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping it definitely helped to fix my problem and my program is finally done! Thank you!